# Opening settings for individual gnome extensions shows blank window

Tags: gnome-shell, settings, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I currently have a couple of extensions installed, and I'm using gnome tweaks to customise my desktop. I noticed that the repository version of gnome-tweaks does not have a settings icon, and instead you just click the extension and a window comes up.

That's fine, except when I click the extensions here:
[image: Settings Screenshot]

I get a big blank window where I assume is supposed to be the settings for that extension:

[image: Blank window screenshot]

Comment: I am still uncertain if you are describing the same issue I see, but someone has opened a [Gnome Tweaks issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/issues/138) for blank/last-cached Details on github. He also included a video. I added the little I have learned; there has been no response from the team yet.

Answer (score 0):

Could that be Details and not Settings?  If so, I am seeing the same issue with Gnome Tweaks on PureOS using Gnome 3.28.  This function worked on Gnome 3.26 with gnome-tweaks-tool.

I get a blank screen too unless I go to Software first and look at any package's information.  Then, I get its information when I double-click any  extension in Gnome Tweaks.

This problem seems to be associated with an assertion error for the extension.
I have no solution yet, but a bit more information is at this link:  [Gnome Tweaks->Extensions shows blank/cached details.](https://forums.puri.sm/t/unable-to-download-updates-from-odrs-gnome-org-message/2938/10)  (I thought I was dealing with a connection problem getting Details, so the original subject line is misleading.)

Comment: You actually might want to post this as a separate question...you've got a lot more helpful information and so you might have some luck finding an answer.